# Scanf seemingly not working after repeated calls (intel x86_64 nasm assembly)

Tags: assembly, scanf, x86-64, nasm

I'm working on a project that is a 4x4 tic-tac-toe game for my assembly course. Right now I'm trying to code a looping menu before I actually implement any functionality. The menu provides three options, each labeled with either 'a', 'b', or 'q'. I can assume that only a lowercase character will be entered as input. My issue arises when the user enters an invalid character (anything other than a,b, or q). I have my menu set up to output an error message if the user enters an invalid character, and then the program will jump back to a label put at the scanf so the user can try again. So when a user enters a wrong character, the error message outputs as expected, but scanf seemingly skips taking in input and my program then ends (doesn't segfault though). Is there something I have to reset/clear before I call scanf again?
Here is my code:
'''

```
extern printf
extern scanf

section .data

    welcome:    db "Welcome to TIC-TAC-ASSEMBLY", 0
    pick:       db "Pick an option from the menu below:", 0
    easy:       db "a - Easy", 0
    hard:       db "b - Hard", 0
    quit:       db "q - quit", 0
    loc:        db "Enter a location on the board 1-16", 0
    notempty:   db "This is not an empty space. Try again!", 0
    win:        db "YOU WIN!", 0
    lose:       db "COMPUTER WINS!", 0
    draw:       db "It's a draw.", 0
    invalid:    db "Invalid input.", 0

    fmt:        db "%s", 10, 0
    fmt_scan:   db "%c", 0
    fmt_o:      db "Entered: %c", 10, 0

    section .bss
    input:      resq 1

    section .text

    global main

    main:
    push    rbp

    .menu:
    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, welcome
    mov     rax, 0
    call    printf

    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, pick
    mov     rax, 0
    call    printf

    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, easy
    mov     rax, 0
    call    printf

    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, hard
    mov     rax, 0
    call    printf

    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, quit
    mov     rax, 0
    call    printf

.getInput:
    mov rdi, fmt_scan ;collects input here
    mov rsi, input
    mov rax, 0
    call    scanf

    mov rdi, fmt_o. ;immediately outputs the input
    mov rsi, [input]
    mov rax, 0
    call    printf

    mov rsi, [input]    
    cmp rsi, 97      
    ja  .aboveCheck ;if the input is greater than 'b', check if it's 'q'

    jle     .end ;otherwise program exits (temporary)

.aboveCheck:

    cmp rsi, 113
    jne .invalidOption ;if input is not 'q' then invalid
    je  .fine ;otherwise program ends

.invalidOption:
    mov rdi, fmt ;outputs error message
    mov rsi, invalid
    mov rax, 0
    call    printf

    jmp     .getInput ;jumps back to input

.end:   
    call    easypick ;for now program just says "YOU WIN" if you enter a correct input

    pop rbp

    mov rax, 0
    ret


easypick:
    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, win
    mov rax, 0
    call    printf

    ret
```

'''
And here is what happens if I enter a correct input:
'''

```
 Welcome to TIC-TAC-ASSEMBLY
 Pick an option from the menu below:
 a - Easy
 b - Hard
 q - quit
 a
 Entered: a
 YOU WIN!
```

'''
and here is what happens when an invalid character is entered:
'''

```
 Welcome to TIC-TAC-ASSEMBLY
 Pick an option from the menu below:
 a - Easy
 b - Hard
 q - quit
 k
 Entered: k
 Invalid input.
 Entered: 

 YOU WIN!
```

'''

I'm assuming I have to reset my input variable somehow, but I don't know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `%c` doesn't ignore whitespace, including newlines.  You have a lot of code, but single-step through it with a debugger to see what happens when scanf returns again after reading that newline.  See other scanf Q&As on Stack Overflow for more about how `%c` behaves, and what you can put in the format string to help with that.  (e.g. I think `" %c"` might work, with the space eating any input whitespace.)

Comment: (Also, I'm surprised you're reserving a whole qword for 1 byte of input.  It makes little sense to use `mov rsi, [input]` when you only want to look at the low byte.  `movzx esi, byte [input]` would make sense, or even `mov sil, [input]` if you don't care about efficiency.  Generally prefer 32-bit operand-size for things that don't need to be 64-bit like pointers.)